# base path for images

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I fixed my problem with the loading times of my pictures, but now the images don't show up on my production system.

My images are in this directory: `\public\images\logos`
At my localhost environment the following paths are working I see the images in my pdf:

```
images/logos/*.*
/images/logos/*.*
./images/logos/*.*
```

If I use the same controller action on the production system, I get an error:

> Message: Cannot create image resource. File not found.

I tried all varieties shown above.

How and where can I set something like an base path for the images and how do I have to name my relative paths in my database?

Additional information:

I try to get the images like this:

```
$pfad = $logen->logo ;  
//$pfad=trim($pfad);
//$page->drawText($pfad, $posX, $posY +11,'UTF-8');
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($pfad);  //Image mit präfix .)/ läuft auf localhost
$page->drawImage($image, $posX-30, $posY, $posX, $posY+30);
```

This works on localhost, but not on my production system, if I replace the path from the database with an absolute path like this:

```
$pfad='./images/fgld.jpg';
```

it works! If I put `./images/fgld.jpg` in my databasefield it doesn't work. So I think it must be an basic error with the pathnames.

EDIT 2:
I tried like suggested:

```
$pfad = $logen->logo ;  //".".
$baseUrl = $this->view->baseUrl() ;
$pfad=$baseUrl.$pfad;
```

I get the same error message like before. I tried to get the baseUrl which is:

```
/cheyenne/public
```

That seems to be ok, so I concatenated the rest of my path, and I get for the first record:

```
/cheyenne/public/images/logos/Berlin_1.png
```

Should be also ok, but it doesn't work. Additional I want to say that my project path on the productionsystem is in the first step under the root, should be also ok I think.

EDIT 3:

I tried the suggested application path, I get a wrong answer:

```
/mnt/weba/b3/45/5543245/htdocs/cheyenne/application/public
```

It should have been:

```
  /mnt/weba/b3/45/5543245/htdocs/cheyenne/public
```

To get a result which works, I tried to add this path absolute like this:

```
$public_path='/mnt/weba/b3/45/5543245/htdocs/cheyenne/public';
$pfad = $public_path . $logen->logo ;
```

I get this one:

```
/mnt/weba/b3/45/5543245/htdocs/cheyenne/public/images/logos/Berlin_1.png
```

which should be right, but with the image statements I get the same error like before.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers I learned some stuff.

I wrote a script and renamed all images in my directory the same way and now it works. It must be one different name something like that.